# Calabash testing on iOS device starts app but freezes on "Scenario"

Tags: ios, iphone, cucumber, calabash, calabash-ios

I have been trying to use Calabash to test some simple iOS apps. I was able to run the app on the simulator and all steps work fine. Now I want to test it on an iOS device, but I am having some problems. I run this command with all the necessary info:

```
BUNDLE_ID=... DEVICE_TARGET=... DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://MY_IP:37265 cucumber
```

After a while the app opens in the iPhone and I get the usual information on console:

```
Feature: Running a test
  As an iOS developer
  I want to have a sample feature file
  So I can begin testing quickly

  Scenario: Example steps              # features/my_first.feature:6
```

But it stays there forever. I left it for a while and it does nothing.

I have tried Appium, as well, for testing and it worked fine both on the simulator and on the iPhone, so I guess is not a problem with Profiles and the device itself.

What could be causing this issue?

```
My setup:
- Mac OS X 10.10.3
- Xcode Version 6.3 (6D570)
- iPhone 4 - iOS 7.1.2 (11D257)
- calabash-cucumber (0.14.0)
- cucumber (1.3.19)
```

#### UPDATE

Trying `curl http://192.168.200.168:37265/version` (as suggested by @alannichols) I get:

```
Failed to connect to 192.168.200.168 port 37265: Operation timed out
```

But I got my test to move to the first step executing the `-cal` target from Xcode (on the device) and running the command:

```
NO_LAUNCH=1 DEVICE_TARGET=... DEVICE_ENDPOINT=http://192.168.200.168:37265 cucumber
```

Still I am getting an error, but this time is a `timeout` error:

```
Operation timed out - connect(2) for "192.168.200.168" port 37265 (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
```

Does it mean that I am reaching the iPhone by somehow I am not able to send requests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the app opens and nothing happens, it's usually to do with the device endpoint setting being incorrect.  The app opens based on the bundle ID, but then calabash tries to interact with the app via the device endpoint.

Try running the app in the calabash console and if it behaves the same way as in your tests it'll be an issue with the device endpoint.  Some ideas of things to check are that you're on the same network on the phone and the machine the test is running on, whether your vpn is interfering with the communication somehow or whether instruments is open on the test machine.

When the app is open you should be able to run

```
curl http://your.ip.address:37265/version
```

and get a response with the version number of calabash.  If you can't get that then calabash won't be able to do anything in your tests.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I updated the question with the (still bad) news. It looks like I am not really reaching the iPhone on the network. I have both, the device and the computer, in the same network and, in principle, nothing is interfering with the communication.

Comment: Ok, I just realized that I was indeed in the same wifi network, but I was also  on a different network with Ethernet. So the connection was being set on the Ethernet connection and not the wifi. Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear you got it sorted!  It can be fiddly at times.